# Bimodule version of IBN

Tags: bimodules, abstract-algebra, modules, ra.rings-and-algebras

Hello all,

Does anyone have an example in mind of a ring $R$ for which $R^n\cong R^m$ *as $R,R$ bimodules* for some positive integers $n\neq m$?

I would be a little surprised if someone showed no such thing could exist, but that would also be a welcome answer.

Thanks!

P.S.: Naturally such a ring could not have [IBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number). I don't recall deciding whether or not the "easiest" ring without IBN (the endomorphism ring of an $\aleph_0$-dimensional vector space $V$) precluded this, so that is a starting point.

Comment: $R=0$ is an example. This also shows that Qiaochu's proof misses a tiny detail ;-).

Comment: @Martin: right. _Nonzero_ commutative rings have IBN... 

Comment: http://planetmath.org/exampleoffreemodulewithbasesofdiffrentcardinality

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth That link is not relevant since the isomorphism is not a bimodule morphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. For a bimodule $M$ let $Z(M) = \{ m : rm = mr \forall r \in R \}$. Then $Z(R^n) \cong Z(R)^n$, so if $R^n \cong R^m$ as $(R, R)$-bimodules then $Z(R)^n \cong Z(R)^m$ as $Z(R)$-modules, and commutative rings satisfy IBN.

Comment: Nice! I should have thought about it longer! The "center" of a bimodule - I think I had one-sided module blinders on.

Comment: This is of course the 0-Hochschild cohomology.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you for the connection. To date I have not had the opportunity to learn anything about Hochschild cohomology.